# Select rows by searching multiple columns and multiple values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
file_id    cat_1    cat_2    cat_3
```

`cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3` all contains category ids.
I want to select files which exists IN `cat1` OR `cat2` OR `cat3`

Simple Query is:

```
SELECT file_id FROM files WHERE 
cat_1 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
OR cat_2 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
OR cat_3 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Isn't any better way to do this? for example putting all columns inside another list ?

```
WHERE (cat_1,cat_2,cat_3) IN (1,2,3,4,5) ?
```

Comment: There is a better way to do this.  It is called normalizing the data so you have a junction table with one row per category and file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better DB design would be

```
files table
-----------
id
name
...


categories table
----------------
id
name
...


file_categories table
---------------------
file_id
category_id
```

That way you can store as many categories per file as you like. To grab all files for a specific category you can do

```
select f.*
from files f
join file_categories fc on fc.file_id = f.id
join categories c on fc.category_id = c.id
where c.name = 'cat 1'
```

or if you already have a list of `category_id`s then do

```
select f.*
from files f
join file_categories fc on fc.file_id = f.id
where fc.category_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```